# Webserver Logs in Azure -> SQL Server

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I'd like to log every Webserver request to SQL instead of to file.

In the Azure Portal I only seem to have the option to save to the Filesystem or Storage.

Is there any way to save to a SQL Database instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to save to a SQL Database instead?

Azure Web App doesn't provide this feature currently. You could post a feature request on following site.

[How can we improve Azure Web Apps?](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps)

Web Server Log use W3C Logging format. If we choose an option to save this log to the Storage. Log file name format in Azure Blob Service are like this,

```
[ServerLogContainerName]>[WebAppName]>[Year]>[Month]>[Day]>[Hour]>[LogFileName].log
```

Azure Web App will save the logs group by hours. We could create a WebJob and use TimeTrigger to read the log out, parse the log file and save data to SQL Server every hour. Code below is for your reference.

```
// Runs immediately on startup, then every two hour
public static void SaveLogsToSQLJob(
    [TimerTrigger("0 0 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo)
{
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection_string");

    // Create the blob client.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Retrieve a reference to a container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("ServerLogContainerName");

    var blobs = container.GetDirectoryReference("YourWebAppName").GetDirectoryReference(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
         .GetDirectoryReference(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString())
         .GetDirectoryReference((DateTime.Now.Hour == 0 ? DateTime.Now.Day - 1 : DateTime.Now.Day).ToString())
         .GetDirectoryReference((DateTime.Now.Hour == 0 ? 23 : DateTime.Now.Hour - 1).ToString()).ListBlobs();

    foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs)
    {
        using (Stream stream = blob.OpenRead())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string line = null;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!line.StartsWith("#"))
                    {
                        string[] fields = line.Split(' ');
                        //Save these fields to database
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

According to the log file, we need to create following 16 columns in SQL Table.

```
date time s-sitename cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status
```